# what can be the antonyms of "motivation"?

Tags: antonyms

What words or phrases can work best as containing the opposite (antonyms) meaning of the word,  "motivation(s)"?

I am trying to find a word that describes the "reasons that make a person not want to do something." For example, watching political TV programs motivates viewers to want to vote. The Watching TV is serving as motivation for political engagement in this sense. What would be the opposite meaning of motivation in this context? For instance, if I want to say "watching political commercials makes people not want to vote (I am making up a sentence here)." What would be the noun form for demotivation? Other words or phrases than demotivation in this context?

Comment: Antonyms are never that easy—they always depend on the context. That said, the most obvious one is _demotivation_.

Comment: Alice, Had you tried to find an answer? What did you find? Can you share your findings?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" antonym. "The" antonym of *man* is *woman, boy, god, robot, alien, animal, mankind*, and probably a dozen others.

Comment: Thank you for these answers. I am trying now to find an answer. It is quite difficult for me to find the answer to this question...

Comment: @Alice: I've no idea whether it's true or not, but you could say *Watching party political broadcasts **puts people off** voting.*

Comment: As others have said, this entirely depends on your actual context (not just your example context), but I'll throw "apathy" into the mix as well.

Comment: All the political ads make me **averse** to watching TV this time of year.

Answer (score 2):

The term **[disincentive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/disincentive?q=disincentive)** means

> a factor, especially a financial disadvantage, that tends to discourage people from doing something: *spiraling house prices are beginning to act as a disincentive to development*

If you need a verb form, at least one source cites *[disincentivize](http://www.wordnik.com/words/disincentivize)*.

Comment: I appreciate this answer very much.

Answer (score 1):

What about the word "discouragement"?

Answer (score 0):

A bit existential, but [placid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/placid).

I suppose in my head, the opposite of being motivated, is being indifferent. But yeah, as previous responses state; depends mostly on context.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read the question and it seems you were looking for a verb. Pacify is a good alternative.